# Jetty - relative paths work in development, not in deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jetty, relative-path

I created a GWT program with a Java Backend running on Jetty. I use relative pathes to access a sqlite database. This is working fine within eclipse.

When I push the program to the web server this approach does not work anymore, because Jetty uses a different working directory. I checked with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Use absolute paths.

   - does not seem to be a good solution though. A different server could have a different directory structure.
2. Tell jetty to use the correct directory

   - sounds like a good solution, but I haven't really found out how I can achieve this. Can anyone give me a hint to point at the right spot of the documentation? I couldn't find it.
3. Exchange jetty with tomcat/something else

   - Possible solution, but I'd rather prefer solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend accessing the SqlLite as a datasource connection, not by file path. The below link explains how to do this.

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3f5369b0aea1a265

Comment: The idea sounds good. But since sqlite is file based I have to put the absolute file path in the config file, don't I?